# How to make UICollectionView scrolling faster

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I displayed number of album images in collection view.
For showing images in cell method cellForItemAtIndexPath contain code as follows.

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

      AlbumImageCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"AlbumImageCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
      cell.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
      cell.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
      if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle  mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"AlbumImageCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
      }

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *inputPath = [[self.arrTbl_Album_Image objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:2 ];

    NSString *imageEx=[inputPath pathExtension];
    NSString *imageName=[[inputPath lastPathComponent]stringByDeletingPathExtension];

    NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",imageName,imageEx]];

    [cell.albumImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      NSData *data= [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
      UIImage *theImage=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.albumImage.image=theImage;
    });
});
}
```

The problem is UICollection view scrolling working slow when i scroll so i need to make is scroll faster.I apply some solutions but still problem not solve.
Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Why don't you put the images in the `xcassets` instead of using the `Documents folder`? It improves the loading speed and your scroll

Comment: @LucaD can u suggest me with some small example,how can i use xcassets instead of document directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. When I profiled the app (while scrolling) I could see that the time was spent somewhere in AppleJPEG (don't remember the exact name). My Images where too big and had to be rendered smaller (for the size of the cell) and this happened to be on the main thread.

Try rendering the images on a background thread.
Check out: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2012-211/

Answer (score 0):

```
[cell.albumImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath]]; // set image on main thread
```

&

```
cell.albumImage.image=theImage;
```

both same

Remove 1st line code

> [cell.albumImage setImage:[UIImage
>   imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath]];

Comment: It seems the first one is like a placeholder

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *docsDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];
 NSString *fullPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", docsDir,[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.item]];
[cell.albumImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath]];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already set image using `[cell.albumImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fullPath]];`

They why you are setting image again using below code. You need to remove that code.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
      NSData *data= [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
      UIImage *theImage=[UIImage imageWithData:data];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        cell.albumImage.image=theImage;
    });
});
```

Comment: it is still working slow for any one of the above statements

Answer (score 0):

This is a huge task to do every scroll

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *inputPath = [[self.arrTbl_Album_Image objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:2 ];

NSString *imageEx=[inputPath pathExtension];
NSString *imageName=[[inputPath lastPathComponent]stringByDeletingPathExtension];

NSString *fullPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",imageName,imageEx]];
```

Can you avoid it? Let's say, using the `xcassets`? For sure, it will be quicker. The background operation to retrieve the image isn't a problem at all, it's in **background**.

**ADDED**: here you can see how to use the `xcassets`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Xcode/Reference/xcode_ref-Asset_Catalog_Format/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015170-CH18-SW1

Comment: can u suggest me with some small example,how can i use xcassets instead of document directory?

Comment: if i add images from photos app in the application folder and after that if i delete those images from photos app then it is possible to get back those images using xcassets?

Comment: Just go in xcassets, right-click on the image -> Show in Finder

Comment: can i add images into xcassets programatically? Because when i add images into my application folder from photos app i created one array which contain list of images. ImageArray-> "<UIImage: 0x7fdfcd319fd0>, {425, 406}"

Comment: No, you can't. They're signed as build resources. They are bundled during the building process and it's a static bundle

Comment: Yes, thats why i am store images in document directory which is selected from photos app. can u tell me i did this all thing in right way or not? Suggest me if u have any better option..

Comment: Ok. So you can try to load all of them before displaying the table into an array. Just display a loading indicator. It could increase a lot the memory usage since you have a lot of `UIImage` allocated instead of 8 as using them into `cellForRow` method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104010/discussion-between-mitesh-dobareeya-and-lucad).